# getLastAccessedTime() in GWT sessions returns 0

Tags: google-app-engine, session, gwt

I'm trying to add timeouts to GWT sessions, by using the following code to check if a session is alive:

```
public boolean isSessionAlive() {
     return System.currentTimeMillis() - getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
.getLastAccessedTime() < timeout;
}
```

I based this code on many examples I saw on web for GWT sessions, such as [this](http://itsecrets.wordpress.com/category/gwt-rpc/).

The above code works great while running on a local web server, but after deploying the project to App Engine it doesn't. The following always returns 0 on App Engine:

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getLastAccessedTime()
```

As far as I understand, the last accessed time is updated on each RPC call.
I made several calls, but this value still remains zero and incorrect result is returned.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround. Adding the following code in war/WEB-INF/web.xml will cause the session to expire after 30 minutes:

```
<!--  timeout in minutes -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Reference: [Session Timeouts with GWT RPC calls](http://itsecrets.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/session-timeouts-with-gwt-rpc-calls/).

Answer (score 3):

**Things  will change after deployed on GAE**

Just today  attended the session on app engine by @roman irani .

> remember that App Engine is a distributed architecture so a difference from Java EE is that you are never guaranteed the same application server instance during request processing as the previous request. While the object is being serialized correctly in memcache, you still have to call setAttribute() every time due to the fact that memory is not shared.

[**Clear cut picture here to handle the session**](http://afewguyscoding.com/2011/02/httpsession-google-app-engine/)

Comment: I got your point, but what could be the solution? LastAccessedTime should be updated automatically by AppEngine and not by programmer, doesn't it?

Comment: @alexgo91 as i just started my app for app engine after the session i attended,my self a noob  here.The docs can throw  light on that  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Request_Timer